# Failed to start route [A] because of duplicate id detected: [B]

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

Getting this error when loading rest definitions via "xml-rests" to Camel Spring Boot 3.2 with the XML path defined in the property camel.springboot.xml-rests = classpath:folder-camel/folder-rest/*.xml

My rest definition file looks as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rests xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-3.2.0.xsd
       ">
<rest id="id1" path="/test">
<get id="id2" uri="/folderuri">
<to id="id3" uri="log:test-log-rest-route" />
</get>
</rest>
</rests>
```

The exception stack trace is

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route first-test-get-id because of duplicate id detected: first-test-to-id. Please correct ids to be unique among all your routes.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:344)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:327)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doInit(AbstractCamelContext.java:2598)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.init(BaseService.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.init(AbstractCamelContext.java:2431)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2448)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.start(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:420)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue [CAMEL-14969](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14969), was caused by producer and consumer route for the rest point being named the same. A possible workaround is to introduce ROUTE tag with the separate ID so incoming rest and outgoing route are having different IDs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rests xmlns= . . . >
<rest id="id1" path="/test">
  <get id="id2" uri="/folderuri">
    <route id="id4">
      <to id="id3" uri="log:test-log-rest-route" />
    </route>
  </get>
</rest>
</rests>
```